# Painless script with Spring Data Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

We are using Spring Data Elasticsearch to build a 'fan out on read' user content feed. Our first attempt is currently showing content based on keyword matching and latest content using NativeSearchQueryBuilder.

We want to further improve the relevancy order of what is shown to the user based on additional factors (e.g. user engagement, what currently the user is working on etc).

Can this custom ordering be done using NativeSearchQueryBuilder or do we get more control using a painless script? If it's a painless script, can we call this from Spring Data ElasticSearch?

Any examples, recommendations would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch orders it result by it [relevance-score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html) (which marks a result relevancy to your search query), think that each document in the result set includes a number which signifies **how relevant the document is** to the given query.

If the data you want to change your ordering upon is part of your indexed data (document fields for example), you can use  **QueryDSL**, to [boost](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) the _score field, few options I can think on:

1. [boost](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost.html) a search query dependent on it criteria: a user searches for a 3x room flat but 4x room in same price would be much better match, then we can: `{ "range": { "rooms": { "gte": 4, "boost": 1 }}}`
2. [field-value-factor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor) you can favor results by it field value: more 'clicks' by users, more 'likes', etc..,
3. [random-score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-random) if you want randomness in your results: different
   result every time a user refreshes your page or you can mix with existing scoring.
4. [decay functions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-decay) (Gauss!) to boost/unboost results that are close/far to our central point. lets say we want to search apartments and our budget is set to 1700. `{ "gauss": { "price": { "origin": "1700", "scale": "300" } } }` will give us a feeling on how close we are to our budget of 1,700. any flat with much higher prices (let's say 2,300) - would get much more penalized by the gauss function - as it is far from our origin. the decay and the behavior of gauss function - will separate our results accordingly to our origin.

I don't think this has any abstraction on spring-data-es and I would use [FunctionScoreQueryBuilder](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-compound-queries.html#java-query-dsl-function-score-query) with the NativeSearchQueryBuilder.